# Different output for binomial coefficient function C++

Tags: c++, int, range, long-integer

I use two method to calculate the binomial coefficient.
one is

```
int fac(int n) {
if ( n < 2 ) return 1; // return 1 when n=0,1
int ret = 1;
for(int i=2; i <= n; ++i)
    ret *= i;  // calculate factorial
return ret;
}
int choose_fac(int n, int k) {
  return fac(n)/fac(k)/fac(n-k);
}
```

The other one is:

```
int choose_dp(int n, int k) {
  int C[n+1][k+1];
  int i, j;
  for (i = 0; i <= n; i++) {
        for (j = 0; j <= min(i, k); j++) {
            if (j == 0 || j == i) C[i][j] = 1;
            else C[i][j] = C[i-1][j-1] + C[i-1][j];
        }
  }
  return C[n][k];
}
```

So when i run on (15,5), the second one give the right answer while first one gives 4. I know that for choose_fac the int goes out of range when calculate 15!, but if this is the reason, why choose_dp doesn't return a wrong answer as they both use int to define the function?

Thanks a lot!

E.

Comment: Well, `choose_dp` doesn't calculate 15!. Just because n! is not representable as an `int` doesn't mean nCk is not representable as an `int`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The first one overflows an `int`.

When you call `fac(15)` to compute `choose_fac(15, 5)` the value that should be computed by the function, `1,307,674,368,000` greatly exceeds the range of `int`. The end result of the computation `15 choose 5` would be in the range for `int` because two relatively large factorials are divided, but an error in the intermediate result prevents this computation from completing successfully.

The second function, which uses dynamic programming, is free from this problem, because it does not compute factorials explicitly. This method of computing binomial coefficients is called [*Pascal's Triangle*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Pascal%27s_triangle).

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But choose_dp also works when calculating (30,15) which result should be out of range. How to explain this?

Comment: If you include a table that shows the state of `C` at the end of the computation, it might make it more clear that `choose_dp` never works with large numbers.

Comment: @Eleanor 30 choose 15 is only 155,117,520, which comfortably fits in an int.

Answer (score 1):

When you return fac(n)/fac(k)/fac(n-k); It is evaluated left to right. (((fac(n)) /fac(k))/fac(n-k)) First evaluation fac(n) gives an overflow error.

Comment: Thank you for the explanation. But choose_dp also works when calculating (30,15) which result should be out of range. How to explain this?

Comment: Pascal's triangle which is used there at depth 30 maxes in about 70 millions, while 4byte int can contain 2 billion without overflow. How many bytes int is using is dependent on your system. Factorial of 15 is about 1 trillion, that is much greater.